# Translation problem of a webshop

Tags: multisite, translation

Some components of some product pages like custom text/name option are lost on a translated site but are kept on the original language. What should i do?

Comment: Unless you have fully custom code handling your store, you'll need to contact the plugin or theme developer directly. Any text in a plugin or a theme that's not coded a specific way to be translateable would have this problem.